# activeadmin: cache filter values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a filter

```
#in cities.rb

  filter :country #drop-down select list with more than 200 values
```

It almost static list, i need to cache it for better productivity

I've tried

```
filter :country, :collection=>proc{cache {options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name)}} #no luck
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**EDIT**: I've changed my code samples based on comment feedback.

**EDIT**: I've update the sample to include html generation.

```
# In activeadmin
filter :country, :collection => proc do
  Rails.cache.fetch('countries_for_select') do
    options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name)}
  end
end

# Somewhere, when you want to expire the cache
Rails.cache.delete('countries_for_select')
```

Comment: i need to cache entire html select not collection of objects for later select rendering.. in your logic i could create something like `City::COUNTRIES=['Argentina', 'Belize', ...]` and use it - it is not my case.. i need cache with all it's possibilities: expiring, disabling in dev environment an so on..

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more involved. Especially the expiring part.

I recommend looking in to [`Rails.cache.fetch`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch)

Oh heck, I'll try editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes searching by country name could be a lot easier:

check this article: http://blog.zeratool.net/2012/02/02/activeadmin-filter-from-drop-down-to-textfield/

Answer (score 0):

Now you have a better option, you can use [AJAX filters](https://github.com/holyketzer/activeadmin-ajax_filter)!

```rb
filter :country, as: :ajax_select, data: { search_fields: [:name] }
```

Comment: looks promising, any chance to see an example?

Comment: Do you mean live example? Good idea, I will take a look